# USB HDD automount problem in Debian Stretch

Tags: debian

I'm trying to automount external usb hdd to my freshly installed Debian 9 box. I'm trying to achieve that with simple udev rule and simply not able to do that. This rule works on my old Debian 6 system without any problem. So rule is created in `/etc/udev/rules.d/11-externalusb.rules`

Rule from my old system:

`SUBSYSTEMS=="block", ENV{ID_FS_LABEL}=="wdext1", RUN+="/bin/mount /dev/disk/by-label/wdext1"`

/etc/fstab entry:

`/dev/disk/by-label/wdext1        /mnt/hdd        ext4    defaults,noauto        0       0`

In Debian 9 this approach doesn't work at all:/ I see the following in the logs: `EXT4-fs (sdb1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)` but I can't see any mounts created. I've searched internet, found some other examples and made another very simple rule:

```
KERNEL!="sd[b-z][0-9]", GOTO="media_by_label_auto_mount_end"

ACTION=="add", RUN+="/bin/mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/hdd1"`

LABEL="media_by_label_auto_mount_end"
```

This rule does not work too:/ journalctl says the following:

```
Mar 23 20:12:48 uranas kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] 2930272256 512-byte logical blocks: (1.50 TB/1.36 TiB)
Mar 23 20:12:48 uranas kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
Mar 23 20:12:48 uranas kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
Mar 23 20:12:48 uranas kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
Mar 23 20:12:48 uranas kernel:  sdb: sdb1
Mar 23 20:12:48 uranas kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
Mar 23 20:12:48 uranas kernel: EXT4-fs (sdb1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
```

But I can't see any mounts:/ If I try to run fsck on /dev/sdb1 it complains that the device is in use. So as for now I completely lost what am I doing wrong. Can anyone help me to automount this usb hdd via udev rule. Thanks.

Comment: Tried mount, tired to enter /mnt/hdd1 directory, no joy. I was able to automount my hdd via fstab entry, which was able to mount disk on boot time, but I want to find what is going on with udev:/

Comment: Output is very strange:/
df /mnt/hdd1   
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on 
/dev/sda2      470992144 11581872 435415496   3% /